# Dynamic importing WASM. Order of execution issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, webassembly

I'm trying to load a WASM library from another **node js** application (Both using webpack). On the WASM library, I have following code to export the functionality.

```
export default import("./pkg")
    .then(s => {
        let result = s.initialize_sync();
        console.log("result = ", result);
        return s;
    }).catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
        throw error;
    });
```

And on the application, I have the following.

```
let s = await import("s-wasm");
console.log("2 s = ", s);
```

I'm getting the following **log lines** when running the application.

```
2 s =  { default: {} }
result =  initialized
```

What I am expecting:

```
result =  initialized
2 s =  { default: {} }
```

I want the `2 s =`  line to be printed after WASM is loaded. but it is called before the WASM is loaded. How do I achieve this ? What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: You are default-exporting a promise. Why?

Comment: because WASM. I'm trying to expose the WASM calls to another lib.

Comment: For anyone following, this was due to webpack not exporting the exports correctly. had to set lib type as "commonjs" and import correctly for this to work. (2 awaits need for importing and to call the promise)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you either write your module as

```
export * from "./pkg";
import { initialize_sync } from "./pkg";
console.log("result = ", initialize_sync());
```

or (if you really have to) with top-level await:

```
const s = await import("./pkg")
console.log("result = ", s.initialize_sync());
export default s;
```

so that you are not default-exporting a promise for `s`.

If you don't do that, your application code would need to be

```
let s = await (await import("s-wasm")).default;
console.log("2 s = ", s);
```

Comment: Tried all 3 of these solutions. Still getting the issue. (What I want is for the "2 s" line to be printed after we are sure the WASM files are loaded fully. ) Thanks for the help though.

Comment: I'm wondering this has something to do with a Webpack parameter